# Unable to maintain context while fetching messages while doing long polling using nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I am working on application that implements chat functionality using long polling technique where db is requested for updates on a timely fashion. I understand that this could be done by using socket.io but i have started off with the implementation using long polling and i have limited time to complete this.

Now, i have an issue while polling for updates in the chat and the context for a given chat id is not maintained. When polling happens, the first opened chat message is retrieved, even when the user is in a different chat box. Any help to fix this is much appreciated.

AJAX function:

```
if(users){

    users.forEach(user => user.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        let imageSrc = this.firstElementChild.currentSrc;
        let name = this.lastElementChild.innerText;
        let receiver = this.dataset.receiver;
        console.log(receiver);
        let sender = this.dataset.sender;
        console.log(sender);
        let countMessages = document.querySelectorAll('#chatForm span');
        let textArea = document.querySelector('.btn-send').setAttribute('data-receiver', receiver);
        swipeChat.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('src', imageSrc);
        swipeChat.parentElement.querySelector('b').innerText = name;

        setInterval(function () {
            //retreive user chat
            $.ajax({
                url: '/getMessage',
                method: 'POST',
                data : {receiver:receiver,sender:sender},
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(response){
                    let oldMessages = document.querySelectorAll('#textArea .incoming');

                    let messages = response.data;
                    let data = messages.map(message => {
                        let html = `<span class="chatMsg ${sender!=message.sender? 'incoming':'outgoing' }">${message.message}</span>`;
                        return html;
                    }).join(" ");
                    document.querySelector('#textArea').innerHTML =  data;
                    let newMessages = document.querySelectorAll('#textArea .incoming');
                    if(oldMessages.length > 0){
                        if(newMessages.length>oldMessages.length){
                            document.querySelector('#msg-new').play();
                            document.querySelector('#chatForm').scrollTop = document.querySelector('#chatForm').scrollHeight;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        },5000);
        }));

    }
```

getMessage.js

```
    router.post('/getMessage',function(req,res){
        Message.find(
            {$or:[
                    {sender:req.body.sender,receiver:req.body.receiver},
                    {sender:req.body.receiver,receiver:req.body.sender}
                 ]
            },
            (err,data) => {
                res.send({success:true,data:data});
            }
        );

    });
```

Comment: do u have any variable to differentiate between two chat boxes ?

Comment: No, Except for changing receiver ids, i don't have any differentiating factor . But could you explain more on how to approach this ?

Comment: That is why you are facing such issue. Try to have an id for each chat box and when you fetch messages you are going to fetch messages only specific to that chat box.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the long polling was switching context with respect to chat id because the previous ajax requests where still active. Hence 'receiver' was receiving multiple user ids when chat box is clicked. To resolve this I used clear interval() function as below:

```
var ajxReq;
var interval;
if(users){

    users.forEach(user => user.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        let imageSrc = this.firstElementChild.currentSrc;
        let name = this.lastElementChild.innerText;
        let receiver = this.dataset.chatreceiver;
        console.log("receiver"+receiver);
        let sender =  this.dataset.sender;
        let countMessages  = document.querySelectorAll('#chatForm span');
        let textArea = document.querySelector('.btn-send').setAttribute('data-receiver', receiver);
        swipeChat.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('src', imageSrc);
        swipeChat.parentElement.querySelector('b').innerText = name;
        if (ajxReq != null) {
            ajxReq = null;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        interval = setInterval(function(){

            //retreive user chat
            ajxReq = $.ajax({
                url: '/getMessage/'+receiver,
                method: 'POST',
                data : {sender:sender},
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(response){
                    //receiver = response.receiver;
                    let oldMessages = document.querySelectorAll('#textArea .incoming');
                    let messages = response.data;
                    let data = messages.map(message => {
                        //receiver=message.receiver;
                        let html = `<span class="chatMsg ${sender!=message.sender? 'incoming':'outgoing' }">${message.message}</span>`;
                        return html;
                    }).join(" ");
                    document.querySelector('#textArea').innerHTML =  data;
                    let newMessages = document.querySelectorAll('#textArea .incoming');
                    if(oldMessages.length > 0){
                        if(newMessages.length>oldMessages.length){
                            //console.log(`RING- ${newMessages.length} ${oldMessages.length}`);
                            document.querySelector('#msg-new').play();
                            document.querySelector('#chatForm').scrollTop = document.querySelector('#chatForm').scrollHeight;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        },1000);

    }));
```

}